# How does a task scheduler fire a job?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

When a task scheduler (e.g. cron) fires a tasks (e.g. cron jobs), does it do so by "polling" the clock every minimum period (e.g. second) or does it registers a callback that gets "pushed" when the time comes?

If it is push/callback, how does the underlying platform (e.g. linux) does it? Is there a "hardware interrupt", or another callback mechanism, for time based events?

So, how does a task scheduler fire a job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intent of this questions was not about CRON, but task scheduling in general using cron as an example, sorry if this was not clear in the question statement.

I wanted to know how the the lowest level software does time-based scheduling, if it must poll the hardware clock or if there is some sort of hardware interrupt for time based events.

It turns out there is actually a hardware interrupt. From wilipedia:

> One typical use is to generate interrupts periodically by dividing the
>   output of a crystal oscillator and having an interrupt handler count
>   the interrupts in order to keep time. These periodic interrupts are
>   often used by the OS's task scheduler to reschedule the priorities of
>   running processes. Some older computers generated periodic interrupts
>   from the power line frequency because it was controlled by the
>   utilities to eliminate long-term drift of electric clocks.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt

So, although cron does polling (thanks @joshua-nelson), it is possible not to and the OS does not.

Answer (score 8):

From the man pages:

> The cron utility then wakes up every minute, examining all stored crontabs, checking each command to see if it should be run in the current minute.  When executing commands, any
>        output is mailed to the owner of the crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in the crontab, if such exists).

Answer (score 3):

The cron on version 7 of Unix had following algorithm:

Its algorithm was straightforward:

1) Read /usr/etc/crontab
2) Determine if any commands must run at the current date and time, and if so, run them as the superuser, root.
3) Sleep for one minute
4) Repeat from step 1.

But this was heavy on system. And use to take a lot of resources for Multi user environment. Then a new algorithm was devised:

The algorithm used by this cron is as follows:

1) On start-up, look for a file named .crontab in the home directories of all account holders.
2) For each crontab file found, determine the next time in the future that each command must run.
3) Place those commands on the Franta-Maly event list with their corresponding time and their "five field" time specifier.
4)Enter main loop:

1. Examine the task entry at the head of the queue, compute how far in
   the future it must run.
2. Sleep for that period of time.
3. On awakening and after verifying the correct time, execute the task at the head of the queue (in background) with the privileges of the user who created it.
4. Determine the next time in the future to run this command and place it back on the event list at that time value.

Modern implementations are vixiecron and anacron. This was superseded by fcron. I don't have much insight on their implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

In may depend on implementation. Some do polling (as mentioned above), but some use interrupt approach (check when next task must be run and set system alarm).

Comment: This is what i'm most interested in, not cron specifically, but how the lowest level trigger is fired. If this is set by the operating system, how does it triggers in turn? Does the OS "polls" or is there some "time based hardware interrupt" of any sort...

Answer (score 1):

> daemons are the programs for running background process. And    Cron
>   is a daemon to execute scheduled commands. And getting these  commands
>   Cron look in to     /etc/crontab or files in  /usr/lib/cron/tabs and
>   if there any command file exist there it Cron executes that. Cron
>   utility is launched by launched process which  replaces init as
>   pid 1.